# argparse subcommand error message

Tags: python, argparse

Consider the following Python 2 code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

p = ArgumentParser(prog="test")
p.add_argument('--bar')
sp = p.add_subparsers()
sp1 = sp.add_parser('foo')
sp1.add_argument('--baz')

p.parse_args(['foo', '--bar'])
```

The error message I get is:

```
usage: test [-h] [--bar BAR] {foo} ...
test: error: unrecognized arguments: --bar
```

This seems to imply that `--bar` is an unrecognized argument for `test`.  But in fact it is an unrecognized argument for the `foo` subcommand.

I think the error message should be:

```
usage: test foo [-h] [--baz BAZ]
foo: error: unrecognized arguments: --bar
```

Is this a bug in argparse?  Can I get configure argparse to give the correct error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I tweak your script

```
p = ArgumentParser(prog="test")
p.add_argument('--bar')
sp = p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
sp1 = sp.add_parser('foo')
sp1.add_argument('--baz')
print p.parse_known_args()
```

the output is

```
1517:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack25333847.py foo --bar
(Namespace(bar=None, baz=None, cmd='foo'), ['--bar'])
```

Parser `p` encounters the `foo`, one of the allowed `sp` choices.  So it now delegates parsing to the subparser, `sp1`.  `sp1` does not recognize `--bar`, so it returns that to the main parser in its list of unrecognized arguments.  The default action is for the main parser to pass it on out, as though it(self) did not recognized the string.

Due its position after `foo`, `--bar` is not recognized by either parser.  Same would go for ['foo', '--boo'].

Delegation to the subparser is done in the `__call__` method of `sp` (the subparsers action).  In part it reads:

```
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    ...
    # parse all the remaining options into the namespace
    # store any unrecognized options on the object, so that the top
    # level parser can decide what to do with them
    namespace, arg_strings = parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, namespace)
    if arg_strings:
        vars(namespace).setdefault(_UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR, [])
        getattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR).extend(arg_strings)
```

So the handling of unrecognized_args is left, by design, to the main parser (the one who calls `parse_args` rather than `parse_known_args`).

---

A different error, such as omitting a value for `--baz` does generate the error message in the subparser:

```
1523:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack25333847.py foo --baz
usage: test foo [-h] [--baz BAZ]
test foo: error: argument --baz: expected one argument
```

---

I have figured out a way of generating:

```
usage: test foo [-h] [--baz BAZ]
test foo: error: unrecognized arguments: --bar
```

though it's not short and sweet.  I subclass `argparse._SubParsersAction`; give it a new `__call__` that uses `parse_args` instead of `parse_known_args`.  I also have to change the main parser registry.  (I can add the code if wanted).

Comment: Great answer. It would be nice to add the code if you ever get a chance to print out a subparser specific error message.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily say it's a bug, but rather a simplistic approach at generating an error message.

The default error message simply states `"{PROG}: error: unrecognized arguments: {ALL_UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS}"`, regardless of what (sub-)parser the unrecognized arguments are associated with.

If you look at how `parse_args()` [generates the error](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/15bfb82194fa/Lib/argparse.py#l1720), it's pretty obvious that this information isn't readily available:

```
def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
    if argv:
        msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
        self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
    return args
```

Calling `args, argv = parse_known_args(args)` will simply parse the known arguments and return them as the namespace `args`, and return all **remaining, unknown arguments** as `argv`.

So you could directly use [`parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) yourself. You could also store the subcommand name to the namespace using

```
sp = p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
```

and then access it using `args.cmd` to determine which subcommand the user tried to invoke.

Based on that, and depending on how simple your parser hierarchy is, you could maybe generate a more helpful error message (see [`parser.error()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error)).

But it's not going to be perfect. If the user were to specify an unknown argument for both the main parser and a subparser, those two unrecognized arguments would remain in `argv`, and I see know obvious way of determining which of them was given to which command on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem with the following:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, _

class _ArgumentParser(ArgumentParser):
    # "parse_known_args" is made to behave exactly like "parse_args".
    def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        args, argv = super().parse_known_args(args, namespace)
        if argv:
            msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
            self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
        return args, argv

p = ArgumentParser(prog="test")
p.add_argument('--bar')
sp = p.add_subparsers(parser_class=_ArgumentParser)
sp1 = sp.add_parser('foo')
sp1.add_argument('--baz')

p.parse_args(['foo', '--bar'])
```

I get the following error message:

```
usage: test foo [-h] [--baz BAZ]
test foo: error: unrecognized arguments: --bar
```

Which I think is exactly what is wanted, no?

I have no idea why Python has `parse_known_args` there. I see zero usefulness there and I would claim it should be `parse_args` there anyway.